# mysql : is aes_decryption malfunction?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT AES_ENCRYPT(  "password",  "abcd" ) aesPassword,
"74b59ffd519b89732cc32bee903ae425" = AES_ENCRYPT("password", "abcd") AS result
```

result of `AES_ENCRYPT("password","abcd")` is not matching with string generated by same.

My MySQL version is : 5.5.44 using on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: AES_ENCRYPT returns a binary string, you compare to a hexadecimal string

Comment: Moreover, at 32 characters, the string 74b59ffd519b89732cc32bee903ae425 looks suspiciously like an MD5 hash.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski : please try SELECT AES_ENCRYPT(  "password",  "abcd" ) it will return "74b59ffd519b89732cc32bee903ae425"

Comment: @AlexK. : how can I convert it to normal string and compare in query itself ?

Comment: @PankajKhairnar For me on 5.6.27, that returns a binary string, not ascii. (which would appear as `t���Q��s,�+��:�%`)

Comment: What MySQL client are you using? Perhaps your client does encoding or hashing on binary values that cannot normally be displayed as text.

Comment: `dLWf/VGbiXMswyvukDrkJQ==` I AM GETTING THIS

Comment: ^^ That is the base64 encoded version of the binary string, @SubinCPoonamgode. Perhaps applied by the MySQL client to make it readable in text output.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski : i'm using phpmyadmin it is converting that string to ascii, when I run select... it is giving me same result as yours